# PHP RSA encrypt with OPENSSL_NO_PADDING mode, return false

Tags: php, rsa

I encrypt password with RSA method, I set the padding mode "OPENSSL_NO_PADDING", it returns false. But if I remove the padding mode parameter, keep it default, encrypt successfully.

```
$pass = 'gmwtwjfws';
$encrypetd_pass = '';
$pub_key = '-----BEGIN PUBLIC KEY-----
MIIBIjANBgkqhkiG9w0BAQEFAAOCAQ8AMIIBCgKCAQEAs+JvfyTOMHqvjxHJyDZG
HZpz3atV7qcOT8mijXGGG3S+8Bb2p2kREGJwrzC2IIErCQUcZ3Wa3wTugKQDxqXE
SPt76HN2353ufegbvTI9kYgK0MLFpY8OZAMsaTytVrvUEVHjqGXZO4z7oVTqByuB
wcZAvK+sN39+MqisS6ZejACbbQLkWZgcSgt5wBAaDaEa2lvRYcVbNyO/mqTU6SSf
d+w78uM07BpmxhimOMwf+l/qs+Z04LUm4Ay7b+AHHAwbaHeehC1wInzNDfipgR0H
0FCa/LOnEblj2HVpptB/NY4XNG+CDHTBKkxzEw92D/Nj1JIlr1oP0l+/VdAnxxiW
uQIDAQAB
-----END PUBLIC KEY-----';
$result = openssl_public_encrypt($pass, $encrypetd_pass, $pub_key);
var_dump($result);  //return false
exit;
```

What's more, I am confused about the public key's format. If I keep the default padding mode, and the format of public key is like above, it return true. But when I modify the key format as follow(remove one new line), it return false. Would anyone explain the reason? Thanks very mush.

```
$pub_key = '-----BEGIN PUBLIC KEY-----MIIBIjANBgkqhkiG9w0BAQEFAAOCAQ8AMIIBCgKCAQEAs+JvfyTOMHqvjxHJyDZGHZpz3atV7qcOT8mijXGGG3S+8Bb2p2kREGJwrzC2IIErCQUcZ3Wa3wTugKQDxqXE
SPt76HN2353ufegbvTI9kYgK0MLFpY8OZAMsaTytVrvUEVHjqGXZO4z7oVTqByuB
wcZAvK+sN39+MqisS6ZejACbbQLkWZgcSgt5wBAaDaEa2lvRYcVbNyO/mqTU6SSf
d+w78uM07BpmxhimOMwf+l/qs+Z04LUm4Ay7b+AHHAwbaHeehC1wInzNDfipgR0H
0FCa/LOnEblj2HVpptB/NY4XNG+CDHTBKkxzEw92D/Nj1JIlr1oP0l+/VdAnxxiW
uQIDAQAB
-----END PUBLIC KEY-----';
```

Comment: Warning: openssl_public_encrypt(): key parameter is not a valid public key. function openssl_error_string will show "error:0906D06C:PEM routines:PEM_read_bio:no start line".

Answer (score 1):

I hit the same problem and found a bug report at https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=61203

The answer to the bug report was that when using OPENSSL_NO_PADDING you have to provide data of the correct size, i.e. by appending \0's.

Now all I need to do is figure out the correct size :)

Comment: Size appears to be 256 byte boundaries.

Comment: But from an API standpoint, what's the point? 

NOT having padding would seem to save you space, so OPENSSL_NO_PADDING sounds attractive; however, you just have to pad it anyways.

Comment: Yes, you have to put Padding in.  What NO_PADDING does is to allow you to do the padding (to 256  or whatever bytes) with your own padding scheme.  I was trying to match PHP encrypt with Java decrypt, and it turns out that there is no common padding scheme between PHP and Java.  But by doing my own padding I could emulate the Java PKCS1 padding scheme in PHP, and then decrypt using the standard Java utilities.

Comment: So, the padding flag OPENSSL_PKCS1_PADDING didn't work for that purpose?

Comment: No, I found a mention somewhere that PHP changed from PKCS1 to PKCS7 because PKCS1 can be insecure.  But they did not change the flag name.  So even though you use the flag OPENSSL_PKCS1_PADDING, it is doing PKCS7, for which I could not find Java decryption.